# frida: Error: a(): argument types do not match any of: overload('int', 'int', 'long', 'java.lang.String', 'java.lang.Object')

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, frida

I'm trying to call a method with this signature `(int, int, long, String, Object)`
The problem is the last parameter needs to be a String array
When I hook it and print its last parameters something like this will be shown:

```
[Ljava.lang.String@abcd1234;
```

And If I pass it, the function works fine
But when I change it to my custom `String` array

Like below:

```js
const arrayList = Java.use("java.util.ArrayList")
const myArray = arrayList.$new()

myArray.add("test")
myArray.add("test-1")

const stringArr = myArray.toArray()

this.a(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3], stringArr)
```

will throw error:

```
Error: a(): argument types do not match any of:
        .overload('int', 'int', 'long', 'java.lang.String', 'java.lang.Object')
    at X (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:563)
    at value (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:967)
    at e (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:547)
    at <anonymous> (/script1.js:94)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:12)
    at perform (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:193)
    at ms_bd_c_h_a (/script1.js:99)
    at apply (native)
    at <anonymous> (frida/runtime/message-dispatcher.js:13)
    at c (frida/runtime/message-dispatcher.js:23)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you let Frida decide which overloaded method to call based on the arguments. As you have noticed this can get complicated (and even mor if you want to pass `null` or other ambiguous arguments).

Therefore my recommendation is to first define the method you want to call and then call it:

```
const cls = Java.use(<name of the class of a>)
const methodA = cls.a.overload('int', 'int', 'long', 'java.lang.String', '[java.lang.String')
methodA.call(this, arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3], stringArr)
```

Comment: im facing the same issue and i tried you answer yet the same error persists i dont understand if frida is reading the method signature with a java.lang.object type for the last parameter how can we change it to '[java.lang.String' wouldnt it be a entirely different method than the one we are hooking

Comment: the problem is if i change the overload the signature frida provides and keep the use the same code as above i get a error pointer expected what does this mean who expects a pointer? and a ptr to what

Comment: @ahmedmani The answer shows how to call a method by ignoring the arguments and their types you provide.  Instead the overloaded method is selected before calling the method that is the major difference to the code from the question.

Comment: ok i understand but do you have a solution to the problem simply selecting the method doesn't fix it

Comment: @ahmedmani Please write a real question. Just from your comments it is not possible to understand your problem. Most likely your problem is different and just the error message is the same.